# Ways of console pausing

Tags: c#, console

As I'm new to C#, I searched Google for various stuff which I used to use in C++. One of them is a pause possibility in a console app.

A lot of people suggested different ways like

```
System.Console.ReadKey(true);
System.Console.WriteLine();
```

Others even showed self-made functions which 'should' be more efficient than others.
And that's a real headache to decide which one is a better solution.

Could anyone give any examples of how C# interpret them and which way should be the most efficient?

Comment: If I may ask - why should *pausing* be efficient!?

Comment: I know that it doesn't make huge different in small apps, but thinking theoretical, which is better.

Comment: Why would you pause it is the first question you should ask yourself.

Comment: Homework assignment, need to print out something in the end of calculations, can't do that without pausing it, right?

Comment: @RnD: the exercise is pointless. There will never be some theoretical situation where efficient pausing is necessary, and even if there were some corner case where it was, you'd be better off spending your time thinking about real problems. This is a case of micro-optimization and premature optimization, both of which are bad.

Answer (score 8):

Run the program using any of the following methods:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

OR as Rajesh suggested

2. `Console.ReadKey() //pauses for any key`
3. `Console.ReadLine() //pauses for enter key`

Comment: ctrl + F5 did the job!

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `do` and `while` to pause the console. Then, if necessary, the console should resume if you press a specific key.

**Example**

```
do
{

/*  while (!Console.KeyAvailable) //Continue if pressing a Key press is not available in the input stream
    {
        //Do Something While Paused
    } 
*/

} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape); //Resume if Escape was pressed
```

If you leave this as `//Do Something While Paused`, the console will only resume if the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key was pressed doing nothing while paused.

However, if you would not like the console application to resume, you can use `while (true);` instead of `while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);`

**Example**

```
do
{
    //break; //Resume
} while (true); //Continue while True (Always True)
```

**Notice**: The console application will pause because by doing `do { } while (Condition);` you are simply telling the console application that you are doing something. So, the console application will wait for the operation to execute. Then, normally close when there's nothing to do.

**Notice**: The `while` is used to loop. So, the application will not close unless the condition becomes false.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the built-in "pause" command, you could always call it -- even though it's ugly. 
Here's what I use:

```
static void Pause()
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    var pauseProc = Process.Start(
        new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "cmd",
                Arguments = "/C pause",
                UseShellExecute = false
            });
    pauseProc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Normally like so:

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive())
    Pause();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The built-in `pause` command just waits for a keypress. Why would you launch an external process to wait for a keypress, when you're in a programming language that can just wait for a keypress?

Comment: Good point, and this was asked & answered 11 years ago. Guess I either mis-read the question at the time, or took it as a programming challenge to call `pause`? Either way, be careful with that "just", I'm sure there's plenty of good logic behind there. Good necromancing though, take your badge! :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use what Pat did but for Arguments instead of

```
Arguments = "/C pause"
```

you can use

```
Arguments = "/C TIMEOUT /t 4 /nobreak > NUL"
```

where number 4 is number of seconds console will pause before executing rest of the program.

And the whole function would be

```
static void Pause(int sec)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        var pauseProc = Process.Start(
            new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "cmd",
                Arguments = "/C TIMEOUT /t " + sec + " /nobreak > NUL",
                UseShellExecute = false
            });
        pauseProc.WaitForExit();
    }
```

and you will call it with Pause function with number of seconds to pause.

```
Pause(4);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

you can write "Console.ReadLine();" this too for pupose.

Comment: This is already covered in the [answer by Rajesh](//stackoverflow.com/a/31239421/1677912). If you found an answer helpful, you should [upvote that answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) when you have earned that privilege.